# Is there a way to create a TypedDict from django ninja Schema or vice versa?

Tags: python, metaprogramming, typing, django-ninja

For this piece of code

```
from typing import TypedDict
from ninja import Schema

class MyDict(TypedDict):
  a: str

class MySchema(Schema):
  a: str
```

is there a way no to repeat the keys (`a` in the example)?

I tried

```
class MyDict(TypedDict):
  a: str

class MySchema(Schema, MyDict):
  pass
```

but it doen't generate the proper ninja schema